# Does Nashorn's RegExp implementation not support Unicode categories?

Tags: javascript, regex, nashorn

I tried matching all letter-like characters within a string using `/\p{L}/ig`. However, this Unicode category doesn't seem to be supported by Nashorn's RegExp implementation.

Is there a workaround or fix for this?

---

**Update**: IMO this is not a duplicate of the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode-regexes): Nashorn 8 does implement ECMAScript 5.1, but since the engine runs on Java, there might be a "Java-way" to change the RegExp implementation used by the engine.

---

**Update**: I installed **Java 9** (OpenJDK) which comes with Nashorn `full version 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246`. Even when running Nashorn with **ECMAScript 6** (`--language=es6`), Unicode categories are not supported.

Comment: Nashorn implements ECMAScript 5.1 (with some partial ES 6 features), and that spec does not define the \p assertion. As far as I can see, there currently is only a proposal for unicode property escapes in ECMAScript regex support, so I would not expect anything to be added to Nashorn in the near future. In those cases I typically just use the native Java Pattern + Matcher classes to work on my Strings.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I know I could use Java's Pattern+Matcher, but I was hoping that there might be a solution that would allow me to keep using JavaScript's simple RegExp definition. For example, a Java option that allows to switch the RegExp implementation used by Nashorn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Unicode Categories are not supported by current ECMAScript RegExp specifications (up to 6.0); e.g.

- https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects

Nashorn is simply implementing the ECMAScript specifications.  To do otherwise would be a bug!

If you really need support for Unicode Categories and other enhancements, consider changing your Javascript code to use the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library.  Alternatively, call the native Java Pattern / Matcher classes from your Javascript code.  Both approaches will require code changes ....

Comment: Thanks for your answer and advice(s). I'll wait 1 or 2 days before accepting your answer to see if someone else might know about another quick fix.